# Erroneous calculation method in C++

Tags: c++, date-arithmetic

I am taking a beginners C++ course and I am struggling with an assignment right now. The assignment was:

> A particular talent competition has 5 judges, each of whom awards a score between 0 and 10 to each performer. Write a program that uses these rules to calculate and display a contestant’s score. It should include the following functions:
>
> • int getJudgeData() should ask the user for a judge’s score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it. This function should be called by main once for each of the 5 judges.
>
> • double calcScore() should calculate and return the average of the 3 scores that remain after dropping the highest and lowest scores the performer received. This function should be called just once by main and should be passed the 5 scores.
>
> Two additional functions, described below, should be called by calcScore, which uses the returned information to determine which of the scores to drop.
>
> • int findLowest() should find and return the lowest of the 5 scores passed to it.
>
> • int findHighest() should find and return the highest of the 5 scores passed to it.

When testing my program it works properly if the score from judge one is the lowest but it will now work properly for any other judges being the lowest.

`Ex: I will enter 2,1,5,4,3 so it should drop the 1 & 5 and come out with the avg of 3 but the result is 2.6667`

the code I have for `int findLowest()` is:

```
int findLowest(int scoreOne,int scoreTwo,int scoreThree,int scoreFour,int scoreFive)
{
    int lowest = scoreOne;
    if ( scoreTwo < lowest )
        lowest = scoreTwo;
    if ( scoreThree < lowest )
        lowest = scoreThree;
    if ( scoreFour < lowest )
        lowest = scoreFour;
    if ( scoreFive < lowest )
        lowest = scoreFive;

    return lowest;
}
```

The `int findHighest` is similar but the less than symbols are switched obviously.

for the `calcAverage()` function I have:

```
double calcAverage(double OneScore,double twoScore,double threeScore, double fourScore,double fiveScore)
{
    double lowest, highest, sum;

    lowest=findLowest(OneScore,twoScore,threeScore,fourScore,fiveScore);
    highest=findHighest(OneScore,twoScore,threeScore,fourScore,fiveScore);

    sum = (OneScore + twoScore + threeScore + fourScore + fiveScore);
    sum = sum - lowest;
    sum = sum - highest;
    sum = sum / 3;

    cout<<"\nAfter droping highest and lowest scores\n";
    cout<<"Your average score is "<<sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: I have put cout statements in the findHighest and findLowest functions to check what number it is determining is correct and each time it selects the correct highest number and for the lowest it will have 0**

**EDIT TWO: I have found that the program sets score one to 0  regardless of what is inputed. The program takes the correct input for the other scores.**

Comment: Can you imagine if there were 100 judges, or even 20 judges?  You'll need a new keyboard after typing in all of that code.   Hint:  Learn arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the suggestion. We have yet to learn arrays in this course so the professor wasn't looking for us to utilize them here.

Comment: I can see an exercise where there are 3 judges and you're asked to code things like this.  But anything above 3 becomes a practical joke if you're told to do things this way.  The way its done with > 3 items is always (I'm not even going to say "almost always") use an array or some aggregate type.

Comment: I believe thats what we were going to cover next so possibly we will receive the same assignment again but with an increased number of judges and the professor looking for arrays to be used

Comment: There's some type confusion here. Everything should be `int`s until you compute the average, why is everything a `double`?

Comment: @Barry you are correct everything should be `int` rather than `double` and I have switched them in my program, but that did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look, the code you have should be working. Run through it again and make sure each if statement is consistent with what you want to do. If that doesn't work another way you could try is

```
double lowest = oneScore;

if (twoScore < lowest)
    lowest = twoScore;
if(threeScore < lowest)
    lowest = threeScore;

etc...
```

Your calcAverage() function is probably only failing because of the lowest() and hihgest() functions.

**EDIT: If you have learned arrays, use it to declare an array of scores then use a for loop to iterate through, as Paul is hinting at in his comment**

Comment: That is actually what I had first and still had the same result. The program calculates the correct avg if judge one has the lowest score but it does not work correctly any other way

Comment: @user3363195 - That's hard to believe that your code was the same as posted in the answer.  Make sure you didn't have `else` in-between those checks, as doing that will definitely not work.

Comment: @user3363195 - Please see the code here.  http://ideone.com/kTSiwu  Take that code and tell us how that differs from yours.  It works perfectly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have found that the issue is not in the findLowest function. For some reason the program is setting score one to 0 regardless of what is entered. It takes the correct input for the other scores just not score one